# Sending an email to a new inserted member in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to an Automation using a file drop. Technically, I listen for a specific drop file, file transfer because it is encrypted-> import the file -> insert the data into DE using SQL query.  Would like to send a welcome email to new contact that I have inserted into DE only.

Do I use filter? Or how can I tell Automation Studio send only to new inserted member.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Import Activity set the Update Type to "Overwrite".  This will clear the existing records of the Data Extension and import all the records in the file.

Comment: I see your point. However, I don't want to clear the previous data as well. For example, every week I would like to update the data extension with new data. So I'm not deleting the previous one. All I want is whatever data I have added into DE, send an email to these contacts.

Comment: Yes, this is a common scenario.  Here's what I would do:  Create a new Date field in the Data Extension and set the default value to "now" (it's a tick box on the field). This will ensure that all new records coming in will be timestamped as they enter.  Next create a query or data filter which only searches for records in the Data Extension that have been timestamped (read: added) since yesterday.  Output the results of the query or filter into a Data Extension and only send to those on a daily basis at a send time of your choosing.

Comment: Fair enough that was my approach